# How to show Spreadsheet Gear Workbook in Webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, spreadsheetgear

I want to show Spreadsheet Gear Workbook in Webpage. I have Google it but couldn't find answer. How to do this?

Comment: Is it regarding showing an excel worksheet on the web-page?

Comment: @Dev i am using spreadsheet gear control in my website and wanted to add that spreadsheet gear workbook in webpage. or u can say its same like excel worksheet.

Comment: Not sure, but this link http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/srcview.aspx?file=chartdynamic.aspx might be work for you.

Comment: @dev this i tried. This is for do something with spreadsheet gear and download it automatically. I don't want to download that instead of this want to show first in webpage and then download on demand.

Comment: You can get the data of spreadsheet in datagrid. Is it the solution or you want to display the file itself as a plug-in on page?

Comment: SpreadsheetGear 2012 for Silverlight would display a workbook on a webpage.  Here's a sample that demonstrates this:  http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/silverlight.aspx?InitSample=SilverlightSamples.WorkbookView.ActiveWorkbookSample .  Of course, this requires the Silverlight plugin to be installed in the user's browser to work.  Is something like this what you're after?

Comment: I've tried a few things.  First, spreadsheet gear does NOT have a native web-based solution.  You either have to use silverlight or find another tool.  AS for other tools, I experimented with componentone.  While it does have a native component, it is not nearly as nice of an experience as, say, google spreadsheet.  It's a little slow to load and slow to use.  For smaller spreadsheets, though, it seemed to get the job done fine.  Worth the 30 day trial to experiment.  Note: doesn't work with MVC4 or 5.